# Pros and cons of package private classes in Java?

Tags: java, class, default, modifier, package-private

I am learning Java recently, and I came across the notion of `package-private` classes, which is the default if we don't specify anything. But then I realized:

1. I seldom see the use of package-private class. Is there a reason for this, e.g., it has serious drawbacks, it is redundant, or simply I am not reading enough? Are there strong arguments for/against its usage?
2. If it is really not useful in most cases, why would it be the default?
3. In what situation should we use package-private in the real world? I.e., when would it become irreplaceable?

In other words, what are the major pros and cons of the default package-private modifier?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The short answer is - it's a slightly wider form of private.

I'll assume that you're familiar with the distinction between `public` and `private`, and why it's generally good practice to make methods and variables `private` if they're going to be used solely internally to the class in question.

Well, as an extension to that - if you're thinking about creating your software in a modular way, you might think about a public interface to your *module*, which will have multiple classes inside it collaborating between themselves.  In this context it makes perfect sense to make methods `public` if they're going to be called by consumers; `private` if they're internal to a class; and `package private` if they're used to call between classes in this module, i.e. it's an implementation detail of your module (as seen by public callers) but spans several classes.

This is seldom used in practice, because the package system turns out to not be so useful for this sort of thing.  You'd have to dump all of the classes for a given module into exactly the same package, which for anything non-trivial is going to get a bit unwieldy.  So the idea is great - make a method accessible to just a handful of "nearby" classes, as a slightly wider `private` - but the restrictions on how you define that set of classes means it's rarely used/useful.

Comment: I can see why someone might have said that - the `protected` modifier is the same as `package private` except that subclasses are also invited to the party.  But it would be wrong to create a subclass relationship (just for access purposes) if one didn't naturally exist.  It wouldn't generally make any sense for e.g. an `EmailSender` class to be a subclass of an `DomainObjectFilter` class or vice versa.  In this situation the method is generally just made `public` (perhaps with a comment saying that it's not *conceptually* public...).

Comment: "dump all of the classes for a given module into exactly the same package -- unwieldy" -- Correct, but I've used this approach even in non-trivial cases, like 20-30 classes in package. Anything bigger, of course, is in need for refactoring.

Comment: Couldn't you organize your source files into a directory hierarchy, and then during build, dump them all into the same directory/package before compile?  That would give you the organizational structure and the benefit of package private access, correct?

Comment: @jrahhali you could that, but I'm doubtful that you'll find an IDE that is willing to honor that. I think it would be pretty annoying unless you write an IDE extension that knows what you mean.

Comment: To make use of package private visibility modifier and also to use modules with hierarchy based modifiers, you can use experimental project https://github.com/odrotbohm/moduliths which works nice for a such scenario,

Answer (score 18):

One nice thing about package-private is that you can use it to give access to methods you would otherwise consider private to unit test classes.  The downside of course being that other classes in the package could call it when they really shouldn't.

Answer (score 6):

Apart from encapsulation, one of the main advantages of using package-private classes is that they do not appear in the javadoc of your project. So if you use some helper classes which have no other use but to help your public classes do something clients need, it makes sense to make them package private as you want to keep things as simple as possible for users of the library.

As an example, you can have a look at a library that I have developed. The [javadoc](http://assylias.github.io/jBloomberg/apidocs/index.html?index-all.html) only contains 5 interfaces and 12 classes although the [source code](https://github.com/assylias/jBloomberg/tree/master/src/main/java/com/assylias/jbloomberg) has a lot more. But what is hidden is mostly internal layers that provide no added-value for a client (typically all the abstract base classes are hidden).

There are also many examples in the JDK.

Answer (score 3):

The package-private access level is more restrictive than `protected`: protected attributes and methods can still be accessed by simply subclassing a class. *Protected* members are (or may be) intended for inheritance while package-private members are not.

Package-private members are often used so multilpe classes inside a package can access *implementation-specific* attributes or (utility) methods.

Good examples to this are the package-private constructor of `String` and the `StringBuilder.value` char array:

```
/*
* Package private constructor which shares value array for speed.
* this constructor is always expected to be called with share==true.
* a separate constructor is needed because we already have a public
* String(char[]) constructor that makes a copy of the given char[].
*/
String(char[] value, boolean share) {
    // assert share : "unshared not supported";
    this.value = value;
}
```

So classes inside the `java.lang` package can efficiently create new `Strings` if the content is already present in a `char[]` without compromising security. You cannot do this from your application because if you could, you would have access (reference) to the internal char array of a `String` which is immutable (reflection not counted!).

In `StringBuilder` (or rather `AbstractStringBuilder` where the implementation comes from) the char array holding the current value `char[] value` and an accessor method to this `char[] getValue()` are also package-private so various utility methods of `String` like `contentEquals(StringBuffer sb)` and `contentEquals(CharSequence cs)` can utilize this for efficiency and faster comparisons without exposing the internal char array to the "world".

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the question of "why would it be the default,", in this context, the term "default" just means the absence of another qualifier. I guess they could have invented another keyword ("package" was already taken), but they didn't.

In the real world, I use default access for utility classes and abstract classes that I don't want people to call or otherwise use from other packages. Let's say you have an interface and two concrete implementations that extend from some abstract class. You declare your two concrete classes as final because you don't necessarily want people to subclass them (see Effective Java). You also don't want people to monkey around with your abstract class for the same reason. If you use default access for the abstract class, then people only see it if they put their class in your package. It's not bullet proof, but I think it's a reasonable use/illustration of default access. That said, the fact that it does not prevent the details from leaking as private would, i.e. doesn't guarantee anything, means that it's not a particularly useful convention.

Another reason why you haven't see it used more often is that people tend to exclude classes with default access from their javadocs.

Comment: He's not misunderstanding the term "default" he's asking why it is the default access-level. One reason for a default is that something is most often used. There are other reasons, and he's asking for them.

Comment: I'm not sure you're right, but I'm happy to update the response for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

1 - Depends on the architecture -Generally if you are writing code just for yourself and on small projects you probably wouldn't use it.  In larger projects it can be helpful to ensure that you can control where and how certain methods are called.

2 - Default (I.e. not public/protected/private) is not the same as private - its a 4th state. See [Java Access Control](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

3 - It can make life easier when you're writing libraries that you don't want third parties relying on how you are implementing the underlying code - you just make the API itself public.

Comment: @BZ Isn't the default package private?

Comment: @BZ Which said: If a class has no modifier (the default, also known as package-private). Thanks for the answer, terminology is trivial:)

Comment: Look at the table of permissions - there is a difference between private and no modifier.  No modifier anything in the package can read it - so not truly private.  This is a HUGE difference from a private class.

Comment: @BZ - the terms "default" and "package private" are often used interchangeably.  It looks like you didn't notice that Ziyao was using a compound two-word term, as opposed to just "private".

Comment: @BZ Yes I noticed that, that's why I said package private. Guess I forgot the hyphen :) EDIT: Okay, hyphen added.

Comment: The default is _package-private_. Nevertheless it is not the same like _private_.

Answer (score -1):

"Package Private" its used when you have several packages, and it means, other classes in the same package can access that class or class member as "public", classes in other packages cannot access, its like "private like them."

Answer (score -2):

Please notice that when you are speaking about classes you have only two options:

1. public classes
2. package private classes

The concept of "private class" is meaningless. (Why to make a class that is not used anywhere?!)

So if you have a class for intermediate operations that needn't to be exposed to API users you are supposed to declare it as "package private"

Also when you define many classes in the same source file, only one class is allowed to be public (its name matched the .java file name). If any other class is defined in the same file it must be "package private".

Comment: This answer is at best misleading. A static nested class is an example where the concept of a private class can make sense. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34551507

Comment: This answer isn't that bad.  It just should be talking about "top level classes" rather than classes.  It doesn't apply to inner classes of any sort, but when you consider top level classes, this is exactly correct.