# How to create my own jOOQ result?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I have a `Result` from a jOOQ `fetch()` that I turn into a `Collection` and then do various manipulations on it.

I then want to turn it back into a `import org.jooq.Result`.  (I confess I want to do this because I want to be able to use functions like `formatCSV`
and 
`formatJSON` so if there is a better way to achieve this, I'm open to it!)

I'm having trouble figuring out how to instantiate the new `result` though.   I've tried several different means:

```
// ResultImpl cannot be resolved to a type
 ResultImpl<R> newResult1 = new ResultImpl<R>( ctx.configuration(), cursorFields );
 ResultImpl<Record2<Long, String>> newResult2 = new ResultImpl<Record2<Long, String>>( ctx.configuration(), cursorFields );
 Result<Record2<Long, String>> newResult3 = new ResultImpl<Record2<Long, String>>();


// Cannot instantiate the type Result<Record2<Long,String>>
Result<Record2<Long, String>> newResult4 = new Result<Record2<Long, String>>();


// The type org.jooq.impl.ResultsImpl is not visible
Configuration configuration;
// ... would make sure configuration was properly initialized
Result newResult5 = new org.jooq.impl.ResultsImpl.ResultsImpl( configuration );
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

---

edit (16-NOV-2015/9:16aEST):

Here is how I did it:

```
        Result<Record> tempResult = null;
        tempResult = getResults().into( getResults().fields() );
        tempResult.clear();

        for (Buffer b : bufferPrimary)
            tempResult.add( b.dataRecord );

        return tempResult.formatCSV();
```

I don't like that the tempResult gets all the records only to clear them out.   Is there a way to add a `.where( false )` to the `.into`?

Comment: *"Is there a way to add a .where( false ) to the .into"* - no there isn't. There doesn't seem to be a good enough use-case for such a `where()` method....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot instantiate the `ResultsImpl` internal class, because it is [package-private](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6470556/521799).

Unless you'd like to resort to using reflection (don't), use

```
DSL.using(configuration).newResult(cursorFields);
```

Comment: I modified the original post to show what I ended up with... I don't really like it, but it seems to work.  What I don't like is having to clear the results - it's inefficient.

Comment: @danielc: Interesting workaround :) You know, you can answer your own questions here on Stack Overflow...